# "Students leaving on campus often complain having roommate problems."

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, sentence-meaning

I came across the following sentence in a corpus called SkELL (Sketch Engine for Language Learning):

(1) Students leaving on campus often complain having roommate problems.
https://skell.sketchengine.eu/#result?f=concordance&lang=en&query=complain

I was wondering whether this sentence is grammatical.  Specifically, I have following questions.

(a) Is "leave on campus" grammatical?
If the verb leave here is a transitive verb, it must be followed by a noun phrase, not a prepositional phrase like "on campus."

(b) Is "complain having roommate problems" grammatical?
I suppose the verb complain is usually followed by prepositions like about and of or a that-clause showing what the complaint is about, but the sentence in question has the verb complain directly followed by a gerund/participle.

(c) What is the meaning of the sentence?
If the sentence in question is grammatical, does it mean something like this?

(2) Students who leave on campus housing often complain that they had roommate problems.

I would very much appreciate your comments.  Thank you!

Comment: @All Please do not answer in comments. If you have an answer, write an answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be **Students** ***living*** **on campus...?**

Comment: SKEll is a rubbish website, no doubt generated in part by AI.

Comment: I agree: SKELL is pretty naff. It should be "... complain **about** / **of** having roommate problems".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a mistranscription (***leave*** instead of ***live***)

Comment: You could put a comma after complain to create a separate participle clause (if you fix leaving).

Answer (score 2):

(a) *Leaving on campus* is 'grammatical', but makes no sense. It is almost certainly a mistake for *living on campus.*

(b) It should be *complain of* (or *about*).

The sentence is an example of very poor English.

Answer (score -3):

"having roomates problem" is a gerund, function as object.  "leaving on campus" doesn't make sense, "leaving campus" or "living on campus" could be sensible.
[image: The following diagram could explain it]

Comment: Please don't use the Reed-Kellogg method of diagramming. It's a dead system, and it has never been taught outside the US.